# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer este array (php)?

Tags: php

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(6) { ["denominacion"]=> string(4) "Test" 
["descripcion"]=> string(4) "Test" ["precio"]=> string(1) "1" ["cantidad"]=>
string(1) "2" ["id_registro"]=> string(4) "7578" ["id_producto"]=> int(1) } 
[1]=> array(6) { ["denominacion"]=> string(4) "Test" ["descripcion"]=> 
string(4) "Test" ["precio"]=> string(1) "1" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" 
["id_registro"]=> string(4) "7578" ["id_producto"]=> int(2) } [2]=> array(6) 
{ ["denominacion"]=> string(4) "Test" ["descripcion"]=> string(4) "Test" 
["precio"]=> string(1) "1" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_registro"]=> 
string(4) "7578" ["id_producto"]=> int(3) } }
```

**Arreglo**

```
$producto = array(
    "denominacion" => $denominacion,
    "descripcion" => $descripcion,
    "precio" => $precio,
    "cantidad" => $cantidad,
    "id_registro" => $id_registro,
    "id_producto" => $id_producto
);
```

Ya probe así y no me muestra ningún resultado

```
 foreach($productos as $producto){
    echo $producto['id_producto'];
 }
```

Comment: Por favor, ¿puedes mostrar el código donde crear tu array, o un `print_r` del mismo?

Comment: Como creas el arreglo?

Comment: $productos=array();
$producto = array(
     "denominacion" => $denominacion,
     "descripcion" => $descripcion,
     "precio" => $precio,
     "cantidad" => $cantidad,
     "id_registro" => $id_registro,
     "id_producto" => $id_producto
    );
$productos[]=$producto;

Comment: A simple vista, tendrás que abrir dos bucles: **`foreach($productos as $k=>$v){ foreach ($v as $kk=>$vv){
    echo $kk['id_producto'];}
 };`** Algo así más o menos. Con el array real se podría probar, pero con un `var_dump` es más difícil hacer pruebas.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [denominacion] => Test [descripcion] => Test [precio] => 1 [cantidad] => 2 [id_registro] => 7578 [id_producto] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [denominacion] => Test [descripcion] => Test [precio] => 1 [cantidad] => 1 [id_registro] => 7578 [id_producto] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [denominacion] => Test [descripcion] => Test [precio] => 1 [cantidad] => 1 [id_registro] => 7578 [id_producto] => 3 ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la  función foreach de php. Veo q tenes varios arrays dentro de otro array. Yo haria algo asi:

```
foreach ($array1 as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $prod) {
      echo $prod["id_producto"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## A. Si quieres leer los nombres de claves y sus valores

Dado que estás creando un array de arrays, podrás leerlos de forma automática de este modo, usando dos bucles:

```
<?php

$productos=array(); 
$producto = array( "denominacion" => "d1", "descripcion" => "desc1", "precio" => 1, "cantidad" => 1, "id_registro" => 1, "id_producto" => 1 ); 
$productos[]=$producto;
$producto = array( "denominacion" => "d2", "descripcion" => "desc2", "precio" => 2, "cantidad" => 2, "id_registro" => 2, "id_producto" => 2 ); 
$productos[]=$producto;

foreach ($productos as $k=>$v){

    foreach ($v as $kk=>$vv){
        echo "Llave: ".$kk. "-> Valor: ".$vv."<br />";
    }
    echo "<hr />";
}
?>
```

**Resultado**:

```html
Llave: denominacion-> Valor: d1<br />Llave: descripcion-> Valor: desc1<br />Llave: precio-> Valor: 1<br />Llave: cantidad-> Valor: 1<br />Llave: id_registro-> Valor: 1<br />Llave: id_producto-> Valor: 1<br />
<hr />Llave: denominacion-> Valor: d2<br />Llave: descripcion-> Valor: desc2<br />Llave: precio-> Valor: 2<br />Llave: cantidad-> Valor: 2<br />Llave: id_registro-> Valor: 2<br />Llave: id_producto-> Valor: 2<br />
<hr />
```

---

## B. Si quieres acceder por nombres de llaves del array.

Puedes abrir un sólo bucle, que te diferencie con `as` las llaves y los valores. En este caso, `$v` será un array en el cual podrás buscar el valor por el nombre de una llave específica. Por ejemplo, para el caso de la llave `id_producto` :

```
foreach ($productos as $k=>$v){
        echo $v["id_producto"]."<br />";
}
```

**Resultado:**

```html
    1<br />2<br />
```